# How to parse ASN.1 with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, asn.1

How do I parse ASN.1 input with Haskell?

Is there a generator that is able to generate algebraic datatype declarations and parser code for a given ASN.1 description file?

(like e.g. [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) for generating C code ...)

A quick summary what ASN.1 is about:

ASN.1 is like Google Protocol Buffers, but is was developed way earlier and it is an actual standard. Basically, ASN.1 defines several methods for serializing hierarchically structured data and a syntax for defining a grammar that describes the structure. Such a grammar can be used to automatically generate a parser and data structures for building a syntax tree.

Answer (score 3):

You can decode binary ASN.1 using the [asn1-encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/asn1-encoding) package, which you can parse either by hand using pattern matching, or the [asn1-parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/asn1-parse) package.

For example the following helper function will decode a BER binary file into a list of [ASN1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/asn1-types-0.2.3/docs/Data-ASN1-Types.html#t%3aASN1):

```
import Data.ASN1.Encoding
import Data.ASN1.BinaryEncoding
import Data.ASN1.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

decodeASN1File file = decodeASN1' BER `fmap` B.readFile file
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of Hackage reveals

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-asn1-0.2.1

which sounds like it might be relevant. I don't really know much about ASN.1...